# Where is this object now?

Tags: javascript, testing, requirejs, jasmine, this

I have to test some RequireJS JavaScript code and don't understand how to replace a special object. This is the code (simplified) of one function within a RequireJS Module:

```
changeView: function (view) {
    function setView(view) {
        this.currentView = view;
    }
    setView(view);
},
```

Now I want to test, if `currentView` is `view`.
But where is the `currentView` object saved?

I tried several things in my tests:

```
expect(view.currentView).toBe(...);
expect(view.changeView.currentView).toBe(...);
```

I also tried to save the inner function as an extra function in the module but I could not access this `currentView` property from within my test. How do I need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
expect(window.currentView).toBe(...);
```

An object called via `this` in a nested function seems to be stored in the `window` object.